# How to flag active customers who have at least one transaction per month?

Tags: sql, hive

Objective is to create a flag for active customers.
An active customer is someone who has atleast one transaction every month.

Time frame - May 2018 to May 2019
Data is at transaction level

```
-------------------------------------
txn_id | txn_date | name | amount
-------------------------------------
101     2018-05-01  ABC    100
102     2018-05-02  ABC    200
-------------------------------------


output should be like this -

----------------
name | flag
----------------
ABC    active
BCF    inactive
```

Comment: and where to find all customers? for example BCF is not in your data. And does it matter in which month customer had transaction?

Comment: i don't understand you?

Comment: Please provide ALL input data sources

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation to get the active customers:

```
select name
from t
where txn_date >= '2018-05-01' and txn_date < '2019-06-01'
group by name
having count(distinct last_day(txn_date)) = 13  -- all months accounted for
```

EDIT:

If you want a flag, just move the condition to a `case` expression:

```
select name,
       (case when count(distinct case when txn_date >= '2018-05-01' and txn_date < '2019-06-01' then last_day(txn_date) end) = 13
             then 'active' else 'inactive'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Comment: I want to create a flag as well.
If ABC has made a txn in all the months except Jan (lets say) then ABC must be marked as inactive

Comment: What do you mean by last_day(txn_date)? 
Do I have to use max(trn_date)?

Comment: @NamanDoshi . . . `last_day()` is a function that returns the last day of a month.

Comment: There is one logical inconsistency here.
For eg - Lets say ABC was onboarded in mid year. So obviously he'll not have any txn before June and thus will be marked inactive.

Comment: @NamanDoshi . .  I don't see any logic flaw.  Your question specifies that they have to be active for 13 months from May 2018 to May 2019.  If you want a different timeframe, then adjust the logic accordingly.These queries count the number of months with transactions.  The timing of the transactions within the month

Comment: Can you pls help me with that?
- Once the customer is onboarded, he has to make at least one txn every month to be flagged as "Active"
Much appreciated

Comment: @NamanDoshi . . . Your question is about 13 months and that is what this answer does.